# Angular 8 App Design - universal object and large calc function

Tags: angular, mongodb, architecture

The app will have an Angular component that will have a list of objects to select.
An object will be selected.

This selected objected will be manipulated by all the other components of the app.

Should the selected object be passed to each component or can it be accessed globally somehow?

The selected object will have an array of up to 1000 items. At some point a calc function will be pressed and then a large calculation will be done on the items. It will have 2 nested loops to obtain an answer for each of the items. Where in the app should this calc function be placed?

I'm using the MEAN stack with Angular 8.

Comment: You are asking multiple questions in one question. Open multiple questions for this and show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The calc function should be placed in the service file of the angular where from any location you can call it and use it by passing appropriate data.

The selection of quality objects can be done inside a single component and manipulated